Firefox open external link in a pdf file in a new window and a new profile
I open Firefox everyday using a profile. However, when I click an external link from a pdf reader, the link is opened in a new Firefox instance (or window) with the default profile.     Note, its not about opening a pdf, but the link inside a pdf.
This problem drives me crazy and I searched the web and found no solution.
I've check the opened Firefox in two windows are in the same version.

This could be more clear. What profile is being used normally? How do you launch Firefox?

A pdf link will usually open the default pdf handler so for example on windows that would normally be Edge thus open a new tab in Edge not Firefox but if Firefox is allocated as pdf handler then click on a link in Firefox should switch pdf page to web page in same tab not open a second window. in FireFox default browsing the one tab can go forward and back between PDF and HTML. perhaps you have more than a simple profile ?

Exactly which program are you using for "a pdf reader"?

@Destroy666 A profile which has my firefox id logged in, and there are some extensions.

@AndrewMorton I've tried summtrapdf and foxitpdf, both of them have this issue

@KJ Note that it is a link within pdf, not a pdf link. Meaning the link is direccted to a normal webpage, not a pdf file.

Just to be clear when clicking a WEB link it will use the system default handler thus this page as PDF in SumatraPDF or any PDF handler will call either the Browser it is imbedded within OR the system handler for the web and since this Edge is active a click in Sumatra adds a new tab here in edge. so now I have this page open several times.

So you just launch Firefox normally and it launches with a profile, but when you launch it from other app it launches with no profile somehow? Still very unclear.

Do you have any other programs (but not a browser, of course) that allow you to click a link and have it open in a browser? You could test with that to see if it is a Windows problem or a Firefox problem.

@AndrewMorton Yes, I have a chat program. When I click a link, it opens in my current firefox window.

You can use Process Explorer to see the command line that launched Firefox (hover over the name "firefox.exe") - are there any profile options for the instance that opened with a default profile?

Although it'll probably end up with me suggesting to refresh Firefox.

When a pdf is opened in Acrobat, clicking on a link inside it opens a new tab on your current browser.  I am sure Firefox will behave the same way.
I am using Acrobat and Brave.  It works fine.
The conclusion is that the OP is that Acrobat is not being used to read the pdf.   This PDF reader has a quirk.

Why should I use Acrobat? This problem should be firefox's. I click a link, it outght to open in my opened firefox window and profile.
